# Difference between IIFE and call

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope

Is there a difference between:

```
(function(){

}).call(this);
```

and

```
(function(){

})();
```

or

```
var MODULE = {};
(function(){
    this.hello = 'world'
}).call(MODULE);
```

and

```
var MODULE = {};
(function(m){
    m.hello = 'world'
})(MODULE);
```

I often see the first case in compiled javascript. They both would create a scope and do their namespacing job well.

Is there any difference or is it just a matter of taste.

**Edit:** And why would compiled javascript would use call over IIFE?

Comment: What do you mean by "compiled javascript"?

Comment: like coffescript, or alloy for Titanium

Comment: It would really depends on what `this` is at the point of calling; in most cases there won't be a difference because all code is wrapped by it.

Comment: Note that a function's *this* keyword has nothing to do with scope, it's always resolved in the current execution context and never on the scope chain. Anyhow, I'd use the second version as to me, the first is just an obfuscated way of passing a reference to *MODULE*.

Answer (score 7):

```
(function(){

}).call(this);
```

calls the anonymous function where the `this` inside the function will point to the object referred by `this` when the call was made.

```
(function(){

})();
```

calls the anonymous function where the `this` inside the function will point to the global object (or undefined in strict mode)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2QrXC/)

Comment: Why most of compiled javascript use call instead of iifee? If I create a function with a call(this), this will be equal to window (global object), so it's kinda the same no?

Comment: @JonathandeM. I think it is a matter of taste rather than any other difference

Comment: Note that in strict mode, *this* in the second example will be undefined.

Comment: But calling the function via Function.call/Function.apply can be (and it is) a little bit slower in some browsers (old IEs). I think, it is due to call of additional function (named call).

Comment: In case anyone was interested in the performance: http://jsperf.com/iife-vs-function-with-call-named-and-unnamed

Comment: I would upvote this about 20 times if I could! BRAVO! (especially the Fiddle, which made it click for me)