# JavaScript immediately invoked function pattern difference

Tags: javascript

```js
(function() {
 console.log('immediately invoked function...');
}.call(this));

(function() {
 console.log('immediately invoked function...');
}());
```

What is the difference between those 2 IIFE patterns?

Comment: Functionally speaking? Nothing I think.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606691/difference-between-iife-and-call

Comment: Thanks,sheeldotme. It is explained very well in that post and I think there is big difference in strict mode about this.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is, that in the `.call()` case, the value of `this` inside the IIFE is explicitly set (by `.call()`'s first argument). In the second case it is determined from the way the function is called.

Incidentally, in this case both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the upper example, the functions context (e.g the `this` keyword) is set to the context that applies where the IIFE lives)

See [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)